# Best way to notify clients for an update?

Tags: c#, database, notifications

Ok, on the server side there's a desktop application which is used to insert some information into a database (news,images,ect..) and i have clients which gather this information from database and store them into their local XML .

So each client downloads news from database and displays them .

The issue is how I can notify clients that there is an update .

**My Solution**

I thought using a database filed like UpdateID ,and on each data update into database UpdateID should be Incremented +1, then every client should have an attribute UpdateID into their XML, and check if their UpdateID matches the Server UpdateID, if not than this is a new update.
On each successful update, clients should place server UpdateID into their XML UpdateID .

So is there any better way to achieve that ?

PS : The Data Re-present layer which im using is a WCF Service

Comment: Your solution seem reasonable. I would only change UpdateId to UpdateDate. This is a natural format for update information, and it will also show when update took place.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your architecture? If your desktop applications are on the same net you might want to notify the clients directly (UDP broadcast or something similar). This might beat having your clients connect to and querying the database.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov UpdateDate would force all client's to do Update's every time their Local Time is Different ,and it will be .

Comment: @AvadaKedavra Client's are on WAN ,so the DataBase is Remote one at a public IP

Comment: @OliThissen Desktop Client Application's and Server Desktop Application are not in same NET ,so Using Socket's is impossible .

Comment: @AvadaKedavra no im using WCF

Comment: @Cody Obviously you should use UTC time for this field.

Comment: The mismatch between the clocks isn't any problem, the client should always return the time the server provided. So the timestamp isn't a local timestamp, it's the timestamp of the local time of the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the pull model that you propose is probably the easiest to implement and most straightforward solution to the problem. Knowing that you are using WCF webservices, however, you have the possibility to implement a push model using `WCF Callbacks`. In this model you write service contracts just as normal but here the clients register themselves on the server. On data updates on the server the server calls a callback function on all registered clients, which respond by fetching new data.

The typical showcase application for this model is a ticketing system, where tickets are booked and released often. This approach eliminates the need for clients to constantly poll the server.

The article called [Eliminate Server Polling with WCF Callbacks](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/38814/1954) gives more details on the subject and also comes with a ticketing system example. [This article](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx) also describes this method.

I am not saying that this is better than what you suggest yourself, but it may be worth looking into.